# Receiving GitLab webhook messages using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gitlab, webhooks

I want to receive GitLab webhook messages via spring boot rest controller but i'm encountering problem with empty POST body of webhook message.

My testing RestController is pretty simple:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gitlab/project")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/ok")
    public String working() {
        return "ok";
    }

    @PostMapping("/fails0")
    public String fails(@RequestBody String message) {
        return "never reaches this line";
    }

    @PostMapping("/fails1")
    public String fails(@RequestBody JsonNode message) {
        return "never reaches this line";
    }
}
```

When I enabled TRACE logging level on root logger, incoming request from GitLab looked like this:

```
[POST /gitlab/project/fails0 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook
Connection: close
Host: 128.71.128.109:8080
Content-Length: 2065

]
```

After 3s timeout GitLab fails test message with exception:

```
Hook execution failed: Net::ReadTimeout
```

After much longer timeout Spring fails with this exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O      error while reading input message; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

If i'm not trying to receive POST payload, request and response is executed correctly, but, of course, this is not what i want.

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/incomoingwebhoook/{a}/{b}/{c}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void incomoingWebhoook(@PathVariable String a, @PathVariable String b, @PathVariable String c, @RequestBody JSONObject msg, HttpServletRequest request){

        System.out.println("incomoingWebhoook: a="+ a+ ", b=" + b+ ", c=" + c+ ", msg=" + msg.toString());


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

the code is correct. The problem is probably the network. If a docker is used, do not use localhost:8080. Use the IP of your local machine or dns.